# How to enable bridged networking in VirtualBox?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I've tried many things I read on the Internet and nothing worked so I decided to post my question here so someone would understand my problem. I want to enable bridged networking in my virtual machine in VirtualBox, but I cannot set this option - [here is the blank list of available bridged networking options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AG4sh.png). So I tried to create a host-only network interface: same result - [error 0x80004005](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nt8hJ.png). If I cannot create a host-only network interface and I don't have any networking card for bridged networking, I went to network options in Windows to enable VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking Driver - [I chose this VB option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXDKj.png), but what I get is this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDkPL.png) - "Cannot add this feature. Cannot find specified module". I even tried reinstalling many times VirtualBox, but nothing changed. I've seen people disabling the Hyper-V but it also didn't work. If someone can help me by sending me websites with my problem or answering my question I will be glad.

Comment: Which eddition of virtual box is installed here? What host, what guests? There was an issue [some years ago](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14604?cversion=2&cnum_hist=20), but it's marked as resolved.

Comment: Note that you can't bridge with WiFi.

Comment: Make sure you have installed Guest Extensions in the Guest machine.